# How to manually download and install linux app packages for Linux Mint?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, software-installation, package-management, live-usb

How do I get package installer files when I like to download them with normal internet **browser** first, instead of using the sudo command line?

I have found two main websites which list packages.

```
https://packages.ubuntu.com
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe
```

For me the archive.ubuntu is not straight forward, It is very easy to find your package, but then there are a lot of different files in the folder and I don't know which files are needed.

**Question 1:** How to know which files I need to download from this pool?

The packages.ubuntu is also easy to find a package but there are these 7 different categories from where you can download packages:

```
xenial/ xenial-updates/ bionic/ bionic-updates/ eoan/ focal/ groovy
```

**Question 2:** How can I know from which of those 7 categories I should download my package (if that package is listed under multiple categories)? What to consider?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Asuming you are downloading a .deb package you can use dpkg tool with the "-i" flag. The syntax is

```
dpkg -i <package name>.deb
```

This will perform a proper installation. Adding the package to the records on your package manager so you can update/remove it properly. The names you mentioned the the names of the releases you need to check in the /etc/issue file release of Mint you are using in order to download the proper file.

Remmembering that if the file is listed under those repositories you can probably install it direclty from the apt package manager.